# URL wont pass second "select" value from ajax input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the ajax data coming in from another page:

```
<? $cat=strval($_GET['cat']);
//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}
$query="SELECT * FROM cats WHERE cat_id='$cat'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="sub_cat">
<option>Select Sub-Category</option>
<? while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?=($row2['sub_cat_id'])?>"><?=$row2['sub_cat']?></option>
<? } ?></select>
```

This is the page its displayed on:

```
<select name="cat" onChange="getSub_cat(this.value)">
    <option>Select Category</option>
    <?php
    //Open database connection
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
                                                }
    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
    }
    //Select categories
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cat, cat_id FROM cats ";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['cat_id']."\">".$row['cat']."</option>\n  ";
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <b>Sub-Category</b></td>
    <div id="sub_catdiv"><select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></div>
    <option>Select Category First</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

AND this is the URL it passes:

```
https://mysitewontworkcom/somepagephp?state=state&cat=cat&submit=submit
```

The sub_cat which is pulled from the ajax into the form does not show up in the URL at all!

The "state" (which is earlier in the form) and the "cat" pull fine?
Any ideas? Please help!

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e)    {       
            try{            
        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
        try{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                    catch(e1){
                        xmlhttp=false;
                        }
                            }
                               }

                    return xmlhttp;
                                }

                function getSub_cat(cat_id) {       

            var strURL="findCat.php?cat="+cat_id;
            var req = getXMLHTTP();

            if (req) {

                 req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
            if (req.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('sub_catdiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                        } else {    
alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
                    }               
                            }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                        req.send(null);
                                }       
                                    }
```

Comment: what do you mean with won't pass? How do you get this URL? Is it a form submission URL or?

Comment: This is the URL when passed to the next page, I need the selected sub_cat NOTICE it doesn't even say sub_cat=

Comment: Yes, its a form submission @BardhLohaj

Comment: can you show the code how you are appending your data from ajax response on the form?

Comment: @BardhLohaj Yes, this is it Whats funny is it works fine on another page so I dont get it!

Comment: no I mean, add the javascript code which makes the ajax request and displays/adds/appends the select element on the form..

Comment: It wont let me post it, says its too long

Comment: are you sure that the subcategory element is added correctly on the DOM hierarchy?

Comment: it  seems like you have 2 select elements with the same name `sub_cat` or am I wrong !

Comment: @BardhLohaj I posted it above

Comment: @Simo its only one element, it uses ajax to pull the subcats to the page when a cat is selected

Comment: @BardhLohaj yes, its correct, it should work. The form works fine. When a category is selected, the proper subcategories appear. I use the $_GET method to submit the form but the sub_cat value does not get added to the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your page that you display the data, you have an error on the html structure:

```
<div id="sub_catdiv"><select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></div>
<option>Select Category First</option>
</select>
```

change to:

```
<div id="sub_catdiv">
</div>
```

As you can see, you are closing the `div` first and than adding an `option` and than closing the `select` which seems like the main issue.

Comment: Okay, good eye! That gives me "sub_cat=" with no value attached

Comment: can you check how the sub category elements are rendered? If you are in chrome, right click and go to inspect element. On the elements tab you can see the rendered html.

Comment: It onlys says `<select name="sub_cat"></select>`

Comment: There is also a stray `</td>` tag in there, just before the 2nd `select`. Remove that and see what happens.

Comment: You don't have any option on sub categories than. What do you expect as a value?

Comment: The selected sub categorie

Comment: But, you don't see any option that you could select, right?

Comment: Are you sure you have any categories with the column `cat_id` set to the selected category id? Your code looks fine apart from the issues we identified above.

Comment: I use the same exact script to form search state then city and it works fine, I don't understand why it wont work here, driving me nuts!

Comment: It could very well be working correctly even if it's the same code but the data is not populated correctly to return any results in the 2nd dropdown. You may be looking for a code issue which doesn't exist due to data not being populated.

Comment: The table is set up `cat_id, cat, sub_cat_id, sub_cat` the stray html tags are just where I tried to take all the unnecessary html out to just post the code, missed a couple @ClarkeyBoy

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy but the expected data populates the dropdown, is there a way to put the selected sub_cat into an array and pass that to the next page?

Comment: How are you expecting the relationship to be between categories and sub-categories? i.e. one-to-one, many-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many? Your current data structure, assuming cat_id is the primary key, would only allow for a one-to-one relationship but I imagine you're looking for either one-to-many or many-to-many, in which case separate tables for cats and sub-cats with a link table would be the best approach.

Comment: Do you see the form filled up with subcategories? Can you select a subcategory on the form shown on your browser?

Comment: That's not right @ClarkeyBoy as this structure of the table would allow multiple layers of hierarchy (cat -> subcat -> subsubcat etc). You don't need to have the cat id as a primary key.

Comment: The form populates the subcategories perfectly, it won't pass the data in the URL. Relationship is one-to-many

Comment: Ok so there is data and the select is being populated. That helps us a bit. How do you get to this URL? Is it an ajax call, or a form submit? If it's a simple form submit then it should work fine as it stands. If it's an ajax call then I don't see any code to build the URL.

Comment: I'm going to try the seperate table approach, it will take me a little bit to seperate them out

Comment: Its a form submit using GET

Comment: @BardhLohaj: I see your point - perhaps a better structure would be a combination of the two - a cat table and a link table which links the cat table to itself. Anyway, now that we know there is data there and the select is being populated, the DB structure is no longer a cause.

Comment: @MartyDemichele: Please can you view the source of the generated page and paste it into jsfiddle or another tool for us to view and play with?

Comment: There are two things that could go wrong:

1. The `sub_cat_id`'s are not being set to the option values correctly. You should check the html with inspect element as I explained on the above comments. If you are seeing the select being populated, that means that it cannot be only `<select name="sub_cat"></select>` as you said.

2. You are closing the form tag somewhere between the previous select element and the second select element or you have some errors on the html structure(part that you have deleted in the question).

Comment: So it would be a waste to seperate the cats and subcats at this time? @ClarkeyBoy

Comment: @Marty Demichele you definitely don't need to play with your db at this point in time :).

Comment: @MartyDemichele: If the select is being populated, yes it would be a waste of time. It is worth considering at some point in the future, however.

Comment: I GOT IT! I feel so stupid I didn't close a tag properly and it caused the hierarchy issue! Thanks for all your help guys, 5 hours and it was something simple....jeesh!

Comment: No problem, and I know the feeling - I've been known to accidentally close the select inside the option loop and stuff like that before. Thankfully dev tools and view-source help a LOT in these situations as you can usually tell when something isn't right.

Comment: No worries @MartyDemichele, you are welcome. Totally agree with you @, dev tools and view-source help a bunch.

Comment: Thanks again, forgive me for being a newbie. I do this as a hobby and was able to build a super nice, super functional site with help from people like you and open source code customized for my needs - Thank God for open source, the DEV community, you guys are great! @ClarkeyBoy and Bardh